# Finding $\int \frac{1+\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}}{1-\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{\frac14}}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to integrate $$\int \frac{1+\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}}{1-\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{\frac14}}dx$$
I tried substitutions such as $y=\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{\frac14}$. But it doesn't help, or at least I don't see it because I get $$dy=-\frac{1}{2(x-1)^{5/4}(x+1)^{3/4}}dx.$$

Comment: Have you tried $\displaystyle u = \left( \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right)^{1/4}$?

Comment: @SimonS sorry, i wrote it wrong it should be 1/4

Comment: but how exactly do I replace $dx$? as I get $dx=-2(x-1)^{5/4}(x+1)^{3/4}dy$

Comment: With this substitution, $x = (u^4 + 1)/(u^4 - 1)$. Then $dx = -8u^3/(u^4-1)^2 du$. So the integral becomes

$$\int -8\frac{1+u^2}{1-u}\frac{u^3}{(u^4-1)^2} du$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with $$t=\sqrt[4]\frac{x+1}{x-1}$$ we get
$$x=\frac{t^4+1}{t^4-1}$$ and $$dx=\frac{-8t^3}{(t^4-1)^2}dt$$ and we get the integral
$$\int \frac{1+t^2}{1-t}\cdot \frac{-8t^3}{(t^4-1)^2}dt$$ which can be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution: $u=\Bigl(\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}\Bigr)^{\!\frac{1}{4}}\iff u^4=\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}=1-\dfrac{2}{x-1}$. Conversely, we obtain $ x=1-\dfrac{2}{u^4-1}$, so that $\,\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac{8u^3}{(u^4-1)^2}\,\mathrm d u$ and finally, if $I$ is the given integral, we obtain:
$$I=8\int\frac{u^3\,\mathrm du}{(1-u)^3(1+u)^2(1+u^2)^2}$$
There only remains to get the decomposition into partial fractions to integrate.